# Trace of Endomorphism on Exterior Algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra

Let $M$ be a compact $n-$ dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-manifold and $f \in C^{\infty}(M,M)$.
Then $f$ induces the differential $Tf: TM \to TM$ on tangent spaces
and therefore via pullback as well on dual spaces $Tf^*: T^*M \to T^*M$ which
extends naturally to a map on exterior algebra $\wedge^{\bullet} T^*M$.
spelling it out explicitely we have for every $x \in M$ a pullback map

$$f_x^*: \wedge^{\bullet} T^*_{f(x)} M \to \wedge^{\bullet} T^*_{x} M,
 \omega \mapsto f^* \omega$$

Assume $x \in M$ is fixed by $f$: that is $f(x)=x$. The exterior algebra $\wedge^{\bullet} T^*_{x}M
= \bigoplus_q \wedge^{q} T^*_{x}M$ is a vector space and then $f_x^*$ acts
as an endomorphism of this space, and we can build a trace of $f_x^*$.

My question is why this identity holds:

$$\sum_q ^n (-1)^q \cdot Tr \ (f_x^* \vert _{\wedge^{q} T^*_{x}M})=
\det(1- T_x f)$$

As Qiaochu Yuan remarked this  is purely a statement about vector spaces. That is let $V= \mathbb{R}^n$ a real vector space and $A \in End(V)$. Let $A^* \in End(V^*)$ the induced endomorphism of the dual space and call $\overline{A}$ the extension of $A^*$ to $\wedge^{\bullet} V^*$.

That is we have to show

$$\sum_q ^n (-1)^q \cdot Tr \ (\overline{A} \vert _{\wedge^{q} V^*})=
\det(1- A)$$

The story looks nice if $A$ is diagonalizable. What, if $A$ is not diagonalizable. assume firstly we can diagonalize $A$ and $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues. Then $\det(1- A)=\det(1-A)= \prod_i (1-\lambda_i)$.

We observe that the dual $A^*$ has same eigenvalues as $A$ and $Tr \ (\overline{A} \vert _{\wedge^{q} V^*})= \sum_i S_i^q(\lambda_1,..., \lambda_n)$ where $S_i^q$ are the $q$-th symmetric polynomials in $n$-variables. This imply the claim.

But what if $A$ isn't diagonalizable?

Comment: This is purely a statement about vector spaces so you can skip all the differential geometry and just work with a linear map. Then you can e.g. rewrite both sides in terms of eigenvalues.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I understand your argument, so now we talk about a matrix $A \in R^{x \times n}$ instead of $T_xf$. but nevertheless this would treat only a special case where $A$ is diagonalizable. Then if $\lambda_i$ are evenvalues of $A$, then $1-\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $1-A$. Then we would have $\det(1-A)= \prod_i (1-\lambda_i)$. This looks fancy taking a closer look on the left side but what if $A$ isn't diagonalizable?

Comment: I updated my question. in case $A$ diagonalizable your idea solves ideed the problem. Could you suggest a strategy if $A$ isn't diagonalizable?

Comment: You can use the Jordan normal form instead, and the trace/determinant are the same in terms of the generalized eigenvalues. There's also a more abstract approach, using various properties of exterior powers of linear endomorphisms, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Linear_algebra) for some of the relevant definitions/formulas.

Comment: You can write both sides in terms of eigenvalues even when $A$ isn't diagonalizable.

Comment: The problem with Jordan form is that we are working over $\mathbb{R}$ and not over $\mathbb{C}$. I think that I found meanwhile an answer why it's sufficient to argue with diagonalizable matrices as Qiachu Yuan suggested: the $T_xf$ is symmetric, thus diagonalizable! But nevertheless I quite curious how that the formula can be generalized. Since in Jordan form the result is also true as you said, the formula holds over $\mathbb{C}$ for arbitrary $A$. What about then case over $\mathbb{R}$ or more generally arbitrary field $F$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I don't know how this can be done. Assume eg $A$ not diagonalizes in $\mathbb{R}$. How $\det(A)$ can be wrote in terms of eigenvalues? Could you give a sketch how this can be done?

Comment: Do you possible mean that we pass to $\mathbb{C}$ and calculate $\det(A)$ as a decomposed in Jordan blocks matrix? So sincerly if $J_{\lambda}$ is a Jordan block with resp eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $\det(J_{\lambda})$ obviously is a polynomial in $\lambda$. Is this the strategy you suggest?

Comment: Yes, that'll work. $\det(A)$ is always the product of the eigenvalues regardless of diagonalizability, $\text{tr}(A)$ is always the sum of the eigenvalues, and so forth.